# ByteBuffer to String in GWT

Tags: gwt, playn, bytebuffer

On a [PlayN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/) project I have the following Java code

```
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

ByteBuffer msg = ... // a ByteBuffer that contains a String
String s = Charsets.UTF_8.decode(msg).toString();
```

this works fine in Java, but when I try to compile it with GWT I get:

`The method decode(ByteBuffer) is undefined for the type Charset`

What's the proper way, in GWT, to obtain a String (encoded in UTF-8) that's inside a ByteBuffer?

Comment: `ByteBuffer` [isn't supported](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation) so how come it doesn't fail earlier? Are you using some 3rd-party library that would emulate `ByteBuffer` on client-side?

Comment: oops, yes, I forgot to mention: I'm using PlayN which emulates java.nio (mostly just Buffers), see https://github.com/threerings/playn/tree/master/html/super/playn/super/java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` after getting the bytes out of the `ByteBuffer` as a `byte[]` using `ByteBuffer#get(byte[])`.
This `String` constructor, along with `getBytes(String)`, is implemented for UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I was looking for a very complex solution, and in fact it was that easy... thanks!

Comment: If you look in gwt super-source, you'll see that String defaults to UTF-8; though, if this is in shared code, Thomas' answer is the cross-platform correct solution.

Nit: Gwt also supports latin using "ISO-LATIN-1" :)